# sequelizeのfindOrCreateの使い方について

Tags: database

sequelize初心者です。
TwitterやFacebookのoAuth認証をして、ユーザー情報をデータベースに保存したいと思っています.しかし、oAuth認証を複数サイトで行うとデータベースに登録したuseridなど情報が他サイトと重複してしまう問題があります。
それを回避するために、指定したuseridが既にデータベースに存在しない時のみ、データベースを更新するような処理を行いたいと思っています。
そのような処理を行うためにはsequelizeのfindOrCreateを使えばいいということは分かったのですが、findOrCreateの使い方がよく分かりません。
upsertの使い方は分かっていて、下のupsertの記述のようにfindOrCreateを行いたいと思っています。ただ、if(userid!="○○○" && username!="○○○")というような条件分岐を行いたいです。

```
            User.upsert
            ({
                userid: profile.id,
                username: profile.username,
                accountid: c+1
            }).then
            (() => {
                done(null, profile);
            });
```

どのようにしたら良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実際に試してはいませんが、[ドキュメント](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#findorcreate-search-for-a-specific-element-or-create-it-if-not-available)には次のようなコードが例示されているので、

```
User
  .findOrCreate({where: {username: 'sdepold'}, defaults: {job: 'Technical Lead JavaScript'}})
  .spread(function(user, created) {
    console.log(user.get({
      plain: true
    }))
    console.log(created)
  })
```

こういう感じになるのではないでしょうか。

```
User.findOrCreate({
  where: { userid: profile.id, username: profile.username },
  defaults: { accountid: c + 1 }
}).spread((user, created) => {
  done(null, profile);
});
```

accountid をどのように生成しているのかわかりませんが、cがカウンタ的なものなら、`created === true` の場合のみインクリメントする等した方がいいかもしれません。